# Laravel Payment Handling

Tags: laravel, payment, braintree

I was just thinking to myself how to tackle an implementation of accepting credit cards through laravel. I want a system to which users can interact with each other and buy things from each other, so I'd be the 'middle man'. Is that legal?

Any ideas?

Comment: This isnt a "laravel" question. Its a payment gateway question. There are many solutions out there, including Braintree and Stripe for starters. And yes, its legal if correctly setup.

Comment: Well I meant the question to be directly related to laravel. I do understand concept of a payment gateway, I was just wondering if there is one that works best with laravel, thus I wanted an opinion. Thank you for the answer to the second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your comment:

> I was just wondering if there is one that works best with laravel, thus I wanted an opinion.

This question is somewhat convoluted, as Laravel is a framework that tries to restrict you as little as possible and therefore works great with everything. So there is no one payment gateway that works better with Laravel.

That being said you can save some work by using client library/bundle written already. If this is your intent you can look for the [existing bundles at this page.](http://bundles.laravel.com/search/tag/payment)